# Form open to controller method - "Unknown action"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

New to Laravel 4. I've created a form within a blade template and I'm following the [snippet from](http://laravel.com/docs/html) which says that you can point a forms action to a controller method by using 'Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method'))'. I've created a new controller called UsersController with artisan and have created a new method within the controller named userLogin(). When I point to that method when opening a form I get an "InvalidArgumentException, Unknown action" error. If I adjust the open action to point to UsersController@index, all is well. I've run composer dump-autoload, but the issue remains.

snippet of login.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'UsersController@userLogin')) }}
```

snippet of UsersController.php:

```
public function userLogin()
{
//
}
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something?

Thanks all. Adding the following to routes.php resolved the issue:

```
Route::post('login', 'UsersController@userLogin');
```

Comment: Can you show how you're routing to this controller? Are you using `Route::controller` or `Route::get` for method in question?

Comment: In the Laravel core, the exception that _should_ be thrown is `throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unknown action [$action].");`. It looks like no action is being passed. Have you set up a route to `userLogin`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like Laravel isn't registering the action you've added, likely because you're missing a route. Try adding something like this to `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::post('user/login', 'UsersController@userLogin');
```

Comment: Assuming sensible defaults for a login page, shouldn't it be `Route::post`?

Comment: Argh, for some reason I thought Form::open would perform the routing for me. Adding 'Route::post('user/login', 'UsersController@userLogin');' to routes.php did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After adding the route to your routes.php, did you also change Form::open()? If not, you can just have your Form post to /login or /user/login.

Also, just because I'm a bit of a stickler for these sort of things, it's common practise to have controllers and models as singular, so UsersController would be UserController, and since the login function is within User(s)Controller, it doesn't need the user prefix. May help your code be more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

Now in laravel 4 you can use this :

```
Route::post('/signup', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'UsersController@userLogin'));
```

Comment: This is not related to the question though. Nothing strictly related to do with using filters or csrf protection.

Comment: Just a tips to add 'uses' rather than 'action'